# Как запустить модуль на PHP?

Tags: php, centos7

Имею модуль для ПХП, при тесте выводит ошибку:

```
РHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'kalkancrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/kalkancrypt.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/kalkancrypt.so: undefined symbol: SetProxy), /usr/lib64/php/modules/kalkancrypt.so.so(/usr/lib64/php/modules/kalkancrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Почему то в ошибке стали два раза выводиться расширение .so
Так же до этого прекрасно работал модуль imagemagik. После установки РНР 7,3,9 и он начал ругаться:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so: undefined symbol: spl_ce_Countable), /usr/lib64/php/modules/<b>imagick.so.so</b> (/usr/lib64/php/modules/<b>imagick.so.so</b>: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Could not open input file: test.php

Соответственно на скрипте ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function KalkanCrypt_Init() in...
```

если заметили то расширение файла после обновления на РНР 7.3.9 стал дублироваться два раза:

```
/usr/lib64/php/modules/kalkancrypt.so.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so.so
```